# Codeigniter input tag attributes

Tags: php, codeigniter

In view:

```
<?php foreach ($all_categories as $v_menu) { ?>
              <input type="checkbox"   id="cat[]" > 
              <?php echo $v_menu->name; ?>
               <?php echo '<br/>'; ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

In Controller:

```
$categories=  $this->input->post('cat');
```

My Question is:
how to send id of this categories, in this situation looping.Because, if that was without loop, then i can use the id number,name field,very easily. In time of loop,how can i use name,id in input tag,for receiving this value after submit?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the view for check box creation with unique id of check box

```
<?php $counter=1;foreach ($all_categories as $v_menu) { ?>
              <input type="checkbox" id="cat_<?php echo $counter; ?>" value="<?php echo $v_menu->id.'_'.$v_menu->name; ?>" name="cat[]"> 
               <?php echo '<br/>'; ?>
 <?php $counter++;} ?>
```

And here controller code

```
//In controller
$categories=  $this->input->post('cat');
if(!empty($categories)){
    foreach($categories as $value){
        $res_arr=explode('_',$value);
        $cat_id=$res_arr[0];
        $cat_name=$res_arr[1];
    }

}
```

It is only example you can change value of check box as per your requirement and get inside controller.

Comment: It would help better!! but i think no need of counter here!!

Comment: yeah agree with you, it will need only when any jquery related work based on check box id

Comment: Avoid `$counter` by adding `$k => $v` pairs in loop.

Comment: thanks @saty, but how can i get of his own category id ? Like, i tick on number 4  category, now i want to get this number 4 in controller using $this->input->post(??)? How? can i write like this : id="cat_<?php echo $v_menu->cat_id; in input tag to get the real id of this category?

Answer (score 0):

This is the view for check box creation with unique id of checkbox and we only need category id in controller so in checkbox value we need to set category id

```
<?php foreach ($all_categories as $v_menu) { ?>
              <input type="checkbox" id="cat_<?php echo $v_menu->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $v_menu->id; ?>" name="cat[]"> <?php echo $v_menu->name; ?>
               <?php echo '<br/>'; ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

And here controller code

```
//In controller
$categories=  $this->input->post('cat');
if(!empty($categories)){
    foreach($categories as $value){
        $cat_id=$value;
    }       
}
```